# How do I increase button size as it is tapped in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am trying to increase the size of the button every time it is tapped. However, I do not know how to go about doing this.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    widthConstraint.constant += 10
    heightConstraint.constant += 10
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    
}
```

Comment: Use uiview animation to animate the button size. Either way you could set button width height programmatically. Google it regarding this technique.

Answer (score 1):

create `IBOutlet` for width and height in your class, `IBOutlet` must be connected in xib file.

```
    @IBOutlet private weak var widthLayout: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet private weak var heightLayout: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

> override updateViewConstraints function

```
    override public func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    widthLayout.constant += 10
    heightLayout.constant += 10
}
```

Call `self.updateViewConstraints()` in your Press button function.
PS reference image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: so what exactly would IBOutlet be attached to?

Comment: its your button width and height constraint. like if you setup your button with 100, and height 50 , in constraints then you can update that constraint in your code.

Comment: will this method update constraints with animation or just update them?@ShauketSheikh

Comment: This code only update constraint, if you want to apply animation you can add animation stuff also